# Caption of subfig overflow into column opposite (Overfull hbox)

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

When using the subfig package and `\subfloat` the caption runs into the column opposite. I've attached a working example.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{revtex4}    % Font size (10,11 or 12pt) and column number (one or two).

\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.85cm, right=1.85cm,
 top=1.85cm, bottom=1.85cm]{geometry}       % Defines paper size and margin length

\usepackage[font=small,
labelfont=bf]{caption}                      % Defines caption font size as 9pt and caption title bolded
\usepackage[font=small]{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[font=small]{subfig}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption.]{
    \label{fig:sub:derivs}
    \input{derivsboth.pgf}
}

    \centering
    \subfloat[Caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption  ]{       
    \label{fig:sub:initialderiv}
    \input{initialderiv.pgf}
}
    \caption{Main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption main caption }
    \label{fig:full:derivs}
\end{figure}
```

My understanding is that the square brackets in `subfloat` can be used as captions. Is this intended/should I be doing something differently?
Thanks in advance!

[image: latex]

Comment: Could it be possible that whatever is inside of `initialderiv.pgf` results in an image that is wider than the actual width of one of the two columns? The width of the subcaption should automatically adjust to the width of the image. If the image is too wide, so is its caption. Conclusion: Try to reduce the width of the image to fit into the column. This should also remove the "overfull box" warning you mentioned in the title of your question.

Comment: I'd have to dig back into my code to double check but I have a standard template that makes graphs the right width for a latex column, and they usually work fine.

Comment: Meanwhile I've found a workaround with `\scalebox{0.95}{\input{...}}` which makes it look ~right, even if it doesn't fix whatever the problem was